# Replace mean of the column using for loop in R

Tags: r, data-mining, data-processing

I have a data-set which contain fifty question (Q1 to Q50) . The value of this question is likert scale data from 1 to 5 . But in my data set i have some missing value so i want to replace missing value by its column mean value . Here is a sample code for single column

```
demodata$Q1 = ifelse(is.na(demodata$Q1),
                 ave(demodata$Q1, FUN = function(x)mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)),
                 demodata$Q1)
```

Now the problem is i have around 50 question in my data set . So its very tough to perform same operation each and every time . How can i manage this using a for loop or any easy technique ?

Comment: `ave` is not needed if you are not grouping the numeric vector.

Comment: Note that for such data the *mode* is more appropriate than the *mean*. Do not treat likert scales as continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `sapply`, to reassign all columns:

```
demo_data[] <- sapply(demo_data, function(col) {
  col[is.na(col)] <-  mean(col, na.rm=TRUE)

  return(col)
})
```

Test data *(randomized and seeded)*

```
# BUILD DATAFRAME OF 50 VARS AND 50 OBS
set.seed(5152018)
demo_data <- setNames(data.frame(replicate(50, replicate(50, sample(1:5, 1, replace=TRUE)))),
                      paste0("Q", 1:50))

# RANDOMLY ASSIGN NAs TO 5 ROWS PER COLUMN (SIMILARLY USED FOR ABOVE SOLUTION)
demo_data[] <- sapply(demo_data, function(col) {
  col[sample(seq_along(demo_data), 5, replace=TRUE)] <- NA 

  return(col)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are doing the stuff with `ave`. This should suffice, not that it is the best way necessarily:

```
for (n in names(demodata)) {
  demodata[[n]] <- ifelse(is.na(demodata[[n]]), mean(demodata[n]], na.rm = TRUE), demodata[[n]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your entire data set is question answers, you can do the following:

```
# generate some fake data
demodata <- as.data.frame(replicate(50, sample(c(1:5,NA), 20, replace = TRUE)))
names(demodata) <- paste0("Q",1:50)

library(tidyverse)
ave_data <- demodata %>%
  mutate_all(~ replace_na(., mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Of course, you probably have some identifiers and such where this doesn't need to be done.  The following version applies the change only to those variables which start with a 'Q':

```
ave_data <- demodata %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Q")),
    ~ replace_na(., mean(., na.rm = TRUE))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `na.aggregate` from `zoo` which by default uses `mean` to replace the NA values

```
library(zoo)
na.aggregate(demodata)
```

#### data

```
demodata <-  data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA), 
                        col2 = c(6, 7, NA, 8, 9), 
                        col3 = c(8, 10, 11, NA, 12))
```